# Stacked Bar Chart with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm a total beginner with programming/ Pandas, therefore, I hope this question is ok anyway. I do need to figure out how to plot basic data of my doctoral thesis in medicine.

What I have:

1) column with different directions of medical specialists e.g. internal medicine, surgery etc. They are listed in numbers from 1-20 in that column.
1) = 'specalties'
2)outcome of patients at day 28: 0=dead, 1=alive, listed just as 0 and 1 in that column
2)='status_d28'

What I'd need:

a stacked bar chart where 1) are listed on the x-axis
and the y-axis shows the total number of patients admitted from each of those medical disciplines for those a) dead at day 28 and stacked on top b) alive at day 28.

Finally, I will need two plots: One with the total numbers of patients for y-axis as stated above and the second one with percentages of the total as y-axis, for example 20% of ALL patients alive at day 28 were admitted to general surgery, on top of that 5% of ALL patients dead at day 28 were so.

I'm sorry for the very basic and unprofessional approach. I'm just getting into the matter and have problems getting started at this one. I added an image for better understanding. Thank you very much in advance.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the first couple lines of data? Either a screenshot or a text rendering of it (CSV, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

If `df` is your dataframe and columns are `0` and `1`:

```
counts = df.groupby([0,1]).size().unstack()

# you could join in the bar labels here, for example:
# labels = pd.Series({1: "Internal Medicine", 2: "ENT Physicians", 3: "General Surgery"})
# counts = counts.join(labels.to_frame("label"))
# counts["label"] = counts["label"].fillna(counts.index)
# counts = counts.set_index("label")

# absolute numbers
counts.plot(kind="bar", stacked=True)

# percents
(counts / counts.sum()).plot(kind="bar", stacked=True)
```